# Saving Credentials in Android / jQuery Mobile App

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, jquery-mobile, android-webview

We're wrapping a jQuery mobile app with a Webview control in Android.  The jQuery mobile app has a login page.  We'd like to allow the user to save their login info.

The trick is that the client would prefer that we not use cookies to do so.

**Solution/Problem #1:**

We've thought about possibly creating an Android login screen that calls an authentication service and stores a token.  The token is then passed into the webview via querystring in the url property.  The jQuery mobile app can then grab the token from the query string and validate it, allowing the mobile app's login screen to be bypassed.

The problem with that, however, is... what happens when the user logs out via the jQuery mobile app?  How can the mobile app tell the Android wrapper to delete the token?

**Solution #2, but same problem**

Same Android login screen, but instead of passing it via query string param, use javascript on the Android side, traversing the Webview DOM and fill in the username and password on the jQuery mobile login screen.  If that token exists on the Android side when you launch the app, just bypass the Android login screen and automatically fill in the user credentials.

That still has the same problem, though, of a user manually logging out.

Are we not thinking about this the right way at all?

Ideas?

Comment: cant u store the credentials locally?

Comment: It looks like I should be able to using the answer from Frenkenstain, but just storing them locally doesn't solve the logout issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use your webviews localstorage. You would have to enable it in your webview using WebViewSettings class:

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Now you should be able to access localStorage with javascript like in any other browser that supports it:

```
window.localStorage
// Set value
window.localStorage.setItem("username", "XXX");
// getting the value
var username = window.localStorage.getItem("username");
```

Alternative 2:
Create a javascript interface to your applications. This will let you create and call a javascript function that triggers java code in your Android application. This topic is described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html under "Binding JavaScript code to Android code"

Comment: Local storage was the way to go.  Thanks!